# Expo app chrashes when executing from deployed instead from development

Tags: react-native, expo

I started to explore a bit more expo, and I found I'm not able to execute the application once I deployed an example project.

It works perfectly from react-native-script and from `exp start` on all the devices, but as soon as I deploy it with `exp publish` and I access to the uploaded version on the iPhone simulator, real iPhone 8 with expo or Snack I got the same behaviour, I open the application `Published Projects` and it just shows the splash and it closes.

Initially, I got the issue described here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9599, just saying as maybe it can be related, even so, I tried to publish without and with the solution in my code.

The code is just published on my https://github.com/robertovg/journal-updated and the expo published of this is here: https://expo.io/@robertovg/journal-updated.

I tried after and before updating all libraries, deleting .expo and node_modules, using the package.json from Expo XDE with SDK 27, the forked expo version of react-native and the real one, with and without the piece of code to avoid the fetch problem, I have  etc. And always getting the same problem, working like a charm as soon as I got it working on my computer, and failing with published version of the expo.

So really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think the problem was with the Expo servers, after changing the name and key of the project to `journal-updated-2` everything started to work like a charm, so not sure why, but somehow and at some point there was no way to update the published application, maybe because I updated the version of the libraries, or because any other side effect on expo CDN or servers.

But the trick works, changing the `slug` of the `app.json` to force to deploy as a brand new one.